# Is a heterogeneous variadic non-type template argument count flexible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

The following defines a variadic non-type nested class template, `DEF`. The non-type template parameters may be heterogeneous according to the type arguments provided for `Ts`.

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct ABC {
  template <Ts ...Xs>
  struct DEF {};
};
```

A `DEF` object can be declared as follows:

```
ABC<int,bool>::DEF<17,true> x;
```

My question is, can the number of non-type template arguments provided to `DEF` be less than the number of type template arguments provided to `ABC`? For example, are either of these declarations valid:

```
ABC<int,bool>::DEF<17> y;
ABC<int,bool>::DEF<  > z;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because `Ts...` is a pack-expansion.

`§14.5.3 [temp.variadic]`

> p4 A *pack expansion* consists of a *pattern* and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - [...]
> - In a template parameter pack that is a pack expansion (14.1):
>
>   - if the template parameter pack is a *parameter-declaration*; the pattern is the *parameter-declaration* without the ellipsis;
>   - [...]
>
> p6 The instantiation of a pack expansion [...] produces a list *E<sub>1</sub>, E<sub>2</sub>, ..., E<sub>N</sub>*, where *`N`* is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. [...]

So both your examples would be ill-formed, since `DEF` will take exactly `<int, bool>`.

Comment: Thankyou Xeo. I wonder how this affects the nature of the `Xs` name? Would the implication from your answer not be that this assigns a name only to the *last* type? I see with Clang and GCC that a use of `Xs...` from the example above can expand to fill a `tuple<int,bool>(17,true)` via `make_tuple(Xs...)`.

Comment: @user: Just because `Ts...` is a pack expansion doesn't mean that `Xs` is not a parameter pack. :)